# jQuery: Can't cache onclick handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a step-by-step wizard kind of flow where after each step the information that the user entered for that step collapses down into a brief summary view, and a "Go back" link appears next to it, allowing the user to jump back to that step in the flow if they decide they want to change something.

The problem is, I don't want the "Go Back" links to be clickable while the wizard is animating.  To accomplish this I am using a trick that I have used many times before; caching the `onclick` handler to a different property when I want it to be disabled, and then restoring it when I want it to become clickable again.  This is the first time I have tried doing this with jQuery, and for some reason it is not working.  My disabling code is:

```
    jQuery.each($("a.goBackLink"), function() {
        this._oldOnclick = this.onclick;
        this.onclick = function() {alert("disabled!!!");};
        $(this).css("color", "lightGray ! important");
    });
```

...and my enabling code is:

```
    jQuery.each($("a.goBackLink"), function() {
        this.onclick = this._oldOnclick;
        $(this).css("color", "#0000CC ! important");
    });
```

I'm not sure why it's not working (these are good, old-fashioned onclick handlers defined using the `onclick` attribute on the corresponding link tags).  After disabling the links I always get the "disabled!!!" message when clicking them, even after I run the code that should re-enable them.  Any ideas?

One other minor issue with this code is that the `css()` call to change the link color also doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Your enable/disable functions worked for me. It seems that you are doing something wrong when you are calling the enabling code, which is why you also don't get the color.

Comment: Do you use JSF? if so try to replace $ with jQuery, other than that, I tried your code on console and it did work. Maybe there is some other parts interfering?

Comment: @Yiğit @SelimOber - You're correct, the code was doing the right thing, but it was being used wrong.  Basically there are some cases that were causing the `disable` code to be called twice in a row, thereby oblitering the cached onclick handler with the placeholder one.  Patched that up and everything works fine (except the CSS colors, which still seem to be ignored).

Comment: @aroth It's about !important. You should remove it or define your styles in css and toggle between classes.

Comment: @aroth: The important flag is not needed here, inline styles should take precedence. If you use the `!important` flag in your CSS files, make sure you remove the space between `!` and `important`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother swapping around your click handlers. Instead, try adding a conditional check inside of the click handler to see if some target element is currently animating.

```
if ($('#someElement:animated').length == 0)
{
    // nothing is animating, go ahead and do stuff
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but simply $(':animated').length might work as a catch-all for all elements on your page if you have a lot of different elements animating.

Comment: Not a bad solution, though I have some animations that run in series.  Do you know if this will work if the user happens to click right at the instant when one is ending and the next is about to start?

Comment: I don't know about that scenario, but I do know it's quick enough to prevent very rapid double clicks - even as my animation starts from a standstill, the second click never slips through.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make this a bit more concise but it should give you an idea... Havent tested it so watch your console for typeos :-)

```
function initBack(sel){
   var s = sel||'a.goBackLink';
   jQuery(s).each(function(){
      var click = function(e){
         // implementation for click
      }
      $(this).data('handler.click', click);
   });
}

function enableBack(sel){
  var s = sel||'a.goBackLink';
  jQuery(this).each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    if(typeof $this.data('handler.click') == 'function'){
      $this.bind('goBack.click', $this.data('handler.click'));
      $this.css("color", "lightGray ! important");
    }
  });
}

function disableBack(sel){
  var s = sel||'a.goBackLink';
  jQuery(s).each(function(){
     var $this = jQuery(this);
     $this.unbind('goBack.click');
     $this.css("color", "#0000CC ! important");
  });

}


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   initBack();
   jQuery('#triggerElement').click(function(){
      disableBack();
      jQuery('#animatedElement').animate({/* ... */ }, function(){
         enableBack();
      }); 
   });
});
```